# C# Conditional equivalent of !DEBUG

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, debug-symbols

What is the C# `System.Diagnostics.Conditional` equivalent of `#if (!DEBUG)`?

I want to encrypt a section of the app.config file of a console application if it has not been compiled in DEBUG mode. This is achieved like so:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    #if (!DEBUG)
    ConfigEncryption.EncryptAppSettings();
    #endif
    //...
}
```

but somehow, I prefer decorating the encrypt method with a conditional attribute:

```cs
[Conditional("!DEBUG")]
internal static void EncryptAppSettings()
{
    //...
}
```

however this makes the compiler sad: `The argument to the 'System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute' attribute must be a valid identifier...`

What is the correct syntax for negating the Conditional argument?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @Gusdor, I used this (I preferred to keep the Program.cs file free of if/else debug logic):

```cs
#if !DEBUG
#define ENCRYPT_CONFIG
#endif

[Conditional("ENCRYPT_CONFIG")]
internal static void EncryptAppSettings()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate folks. I had failed to find it. Sadly the accepted answer over there was "it can't be done" whereas, here I managed to get a solution. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the attribute will be a bit of a hack but it can be done.

```
#if DEBUG
//you have nothing to do here but c# requires it
#else
#define NOT_DEBUG //define a symbol specifying a non debug environment
#endif

[Conditional("NOT_DEBUG")]
internal static void EncryptAppSettings()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: That is quite a big thing to ask of the calling code; it'll work when you control everything, but I'm not sure it works well in the general case

Comment: Thanks! I based my implementation on your idea (just dropped the `else` logic in favour of a negation).

Comment: @MarcGravell if i run up a new stack would you be able to illustrate some cases in which it will fail?

Comment: My point is that in a *library* scenario; `[Conditional(...)]` is part of the library. If is not obvious to the consumer of a library that they would need to start adding compiler symbols to get the library to behave correctly.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that @Marc. I failed to see the downside earlier, but you're very right, the conditional hides the switch behind a magic symbol, which wouldn't be nice in a lib.

Comment: why not just ?

    #if !DEBUG
    #define NOT_DEBUG //define a symbol specifying a non debug  environment
    #endif
`

Answer (score 0):

```
#if DEBUG
    // do nothing
#else
   //your code here
#endif
```

Comment: The problem with this is that during normal development, anything in the #else block can stop compiling (eg. after refactoring) and you won't be any the wiser until you next build in release mode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361149/c-sharp-conditional-equivalent-of-debug

Comment: @Dan that's more about how well CI/CD pipeline works than about the solution itself

Comment: I didn't mean CI/CD pipelines. I'm talking about the compiler. If you build your application in debug mode, then the compiler won't attempt to compile anything in the `#else` block, and vice-versa. That means if elsewhere in code, you're refactored something that breaks something in the `#else` block, you won't know about it when building in debug mode.